# Windows 8 Desktop IE - Pin to Start

Tags: windows-8-preview, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

The **Metro** version of IE 10 has a nifty - Pin to Start button.  The benefit is that one can have a whole column of tiles to one's favourite websites.

However, the **Desktop** version of IE 10 has no such option to create a tile of a website that I am visiting.

Question: Is there indeed a 'Pin to Start' option for the DESKTOP version of IE 10, but I just cannot find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - desktop IE cannot create shortcut tiles on your Metro start page.

Consider Metro as an isolated environment protected from potential attack/control/influence from apps running on your desktop. Apps running in the Windows desktop have VERY little influence and/or control over Metro apps, start screen and environment. In fact, there are almost no API's available to desktop app developers to interact with Metro at all - pretty much the only thing they can do is open the start page!

Even Metro apps themselves cannot interact with one another other than through very well defined and system-controlled "contracts".

This is a good thing :)

The desktop version of IE can host 3rd party controls and extensions (e.g. flash), and so could be compromized. The Metro IE browser does not permit extensions and so can keep you far safer. Using the Metro browser, you'll see far fewer errors, crashes, hangs, slow-downs, etc.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an 'Add site to Start Screen' option in the Tools menu that pins the site to the Metro start page.

You can get to the Tools menu by clicking the cog wheel in the top right. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way of choosing your own name for the pinned site.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Desktop Internet Explorer as your default IE version and then Pins will be opened with it. Go to Tools -> Internet Options - > Programs -> Choose how you open links.

There, select *Always in Internet Explorer on the desktop* and also check the option which says *Open Internet Explorer tiles on the desktop*.